# Great Answers, Wrong Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've written a question: [How do I benchmark Emacs performance?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/539/304)

What I wanted to know (and clearly I worded it poorly) was whether there were any existing benchmarks of the performance of Emacs itself. Something similar to how [the V8 JS interpreter team have a standard benchmark](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v7/run.html).

(I suspect the answer is no, but I hoped the community might know of something, or that a large external elisp package might have written a benchmark.)

The answers I received were about how to write a benchmark, not existing benchmarks. However, I received several answers, all focused on the same thing.

The answers are useful, and well written, but not what I was looking for. **Should I edit my question to match the answers and write another question**?

Comment: If you're ok with that I see no problem with doing it. If you prefer to edit your current question to better express your original intention, that's perfectly fine as well, in which case I'll edit my answer to indicate my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely; if all the answers are for the same (mis-interpreted) question, by far the nicest thing to do would be to edit the question to match, and then ask a *new* question (with less ambiguous wording).

(And better to do it sooner rather than later, in case someone answers it the way you had originally intended :)

Given the confusion, you might like to cross-link the two questions once you're done, in order to make the distinction as clear as possible.

Comment: Done! I've reworded the original question to [How do I measure performance of elisp code?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/539/304) and opened [Are there any pre-existing benchmark suites for Emacs itself?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/655/304)